# How can I configure Apache to reject all requests except an XMLHttpRequest from localhost?

Tags: apache, xmlhttprequest, mod-wsgi

I have a Flask website, served with mod_wsgi (3.4) and Apache (2.4.7) on Ubuntu 14.04. The virtual host config has two directory blocks – one for the Flask app, and one for a directory of static files, which the Flask app sometimes fetches via an `XMLHttpRequest`.

I'd like the directory of static files to be accessible only to requests from the Flask app, but am having trouble setting Apache up to do this. I've tried `Require local`, `Require ip 127.0.0.1` and `Require sd.d.com` but each of these causes a 403 for the `XMLHttpRequest`.

[The `XMLHttpRequest` works fine with `Require all granted` (and the Flask app and static directory are on the same subdomain, server and port), so I don't think it's a CORS-related issue.]

Here's my Apache conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName sd.d.com
  WSGIDaemonProcess mag user=www-data group=www-data threads=5 python-path=/var/www/sd.d.com:/var/www/sd.d.com/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages
  WSGIProcessGroup mag
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/sd.d.com/mag.wsgi
  <Directory /var/www/sd.d.com>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  Alias /models /var/www/sd.d.com/models
  <Directory /var/www/sd.d.com/models>
    Require local # Tried this
    # Require ip 127.0.0.1 # Also tried this
    # Require host sd.d.com # Also tried this
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog /var/www/sd.d.com/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/sd.d.com/access.log combined
  LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>
```

Here's a sample from my access.log after a 403:

```
02dec1b9.bb.sky.com - - [27/Apr/2016:19:02:49 +0000] "GET /models/cbc96411-aa47-4417-bea4-95943b98b1d3/cbc96411-aa47-4417-bea4-95943b98b1d3.stl HTTP/1.1" 403 581 "http://sd.d.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.86 Safari/537.36"
```

Don't know if this is related, but I was expecting the `XMLHttpRequest` request to come from localhost rather than 02dec1b9.bb.sky.com. My access log file is set up as below:

```
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
```

The same failed request from my error.log:

```
[Wed Apr 27 19:02:49.381706 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 18700:tid 140508152153856] [client 2.222.193.185:59865] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/sd.d.com/models/cbc96411-aa47-4417-bea4-95943b98b1d3/cbc96411-aa47-4417-bea4-95943b98b1d3.stl, referer: http://sd.d.com/
```

How can I configure Apache to reject all requests except the desired `XMLHttpRequest`?

**Update**

If I set the models/ directory to `Require all granted` the successful `XMLHttpRequest` is logged as 2.222.193.185 rather than 02dec1b9.bb.sky.com:

```
2.222.193.185 - - [28/Apr/2016:09:41:02 +0000] "GET /models/ca19d6ca-715e-4a0f-89f0-f5e3059f57ff/ca19d6ca-715e-4a0f-89f0-f5e3059f57ff.stl HTTP/1.1" 200 4426280 "http://sd.d.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.86 Safari/537.36"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently setting [a variable in Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/access.html) like this if the referer matches my website's domain:

```
<Directory /var/www/sd.d.com/models>
  SetEnvIf Referer sd\.d\.com local_request
  Require env local_request
</Directory>
```

I know the referer can be spoofed, but this is probably secure enough for my purposes.

Would be interested to hear of any other solutions!